# No puedo Instalar React-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

hago npm install react-router-dom y me sale que tengo muchas vulnerabilidades que no lo puedo instalar. Le doy a la recomendación de fix e igual no lo soluciona.
Hay otra manera de instalarlo?
Gracias!

```
  npm install react-router-dom
    
    up to date, audited 1927 packages in 8s
    
    102 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details
    
    75 vulnerabilities (12 low, 17 moderate, 42 high, 4 critical)
    
    To address issues that do not require attention, run:
      npm audit fix
    
    To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
      npm audit fix --force
    
    Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: No dice que no lo instaló, solo te dice que hay vulnerabilidades.

Comment: Hola, pero las vulnerabilidades no me las repara e igual es como que no me estaría funcionando.

Comment: Y en tu ``package.json`` que version de ``react`` y de ``react-router-dom`` estas usando?

Comment: Fijate de hacer ``npm remove react-router-dom`` y despues que lo desinstales fijate cuantas vulnerabilidades tenes. Si no lo ves, hace ``npm audit``. Capaz algunas vulnerabilidades las tenias desde antes de instalar el router. Despues de eso, habria que ver que version de react estas usando para buscar una version de RRD que ande bien.

Comment: mm probé eso y otras soluciones en línea siguiendo lo que dijiste pero igual no me routea bien.      
"react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
esas son las versiones que tengo. Despues de remover igual me salieron las vulnerabilidades, le puse fix --force

Comment: npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit Updating react-scripts to 5.0.1, which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead

added 573 packages, removed 1014 packages, changed 348 packages, and audited 1483 packages in 1m

233 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

Comment: nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
 css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select

Comment: svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          node_modules/react-scripts

6 high severity vulnerabilities

(estoy recién empezando en el tema también)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a hacerlo de esta forma:

```
npm install react-router-dom@6
```